# Can't SSH into Pi Model A from PUTTY on Windows (even though I can ping from cmd)

Tags: wifi, ssh, putty

I set up a model A RPi to boot up with `wlan0` and have a static IP address like so:

In `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1xx
gateway 192.168.0.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0

iface default inet dhcp
```

In `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
  ssid="xxxxx"
  psk="xxxxx"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP TKIP
  group=CCMP TKIP
}
```

This being a model A, I can't plug in the USB keyboard *and* the USB wifi dongle at the same time. My strategy is to `sudo reboot`, remove the keyboard USB, and replace it with the wifi dongle. When the RPi boots up, I can see on the screen that it recognizes the wifi dongle and assigns the RPi the static IP I chose.

I then go to my Windows laptop, open up `cmd`, and `ping` the RPi static IP address. Success! However, when I open up PUTTY and try to SSH into the RPi at that IP address on Port 22, I get the dreaded "Connection refused" error.

Things I've tried to get rid of "Connection refused":

- Disabling/re-enabling SSH in `raspi-config` and rebooting (didn't change anything)
- SSH-ing into the RPi's localhost `ssh 127.0.0.1` (successful)
- Checking RPi's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to make sure it's listening on Port 22 (it is)
- Disabling Windows Firewall entirely (didn't work)
- Changing the RPi's static IP (to another `.1xx`) to make sure it's not overlapping with another one on the network

I'm a bit lost at this point. It'd really make this project easier if I could type on the RPi *and* connect to the internet at the same time :P Any other ideas?

Comment: no error log, no error message. The `sshd` server usually provides information why it did refused the connection.

Comment: try the vnc server if it works until you fix the ssh, you wont need a keyboard attached to pi then.